# What is the correct bracha for those Israeli aloe drinks?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, state-of-israel

I'm talking about the delicious drinks like [PurAloe](http://puraloevera.com/puraloe-original.html) that contain liquid and numerous chewable bubbles of pulp. You really have to and do chew the bubbles. So is it possible that one should follow the usual rules for soup and make a separate bracha (HaAdama?) on the solids? That it would be difficult to separate the parts seems to me only a reason to avoid the drink, not to make a less-than-ideal bracha on it.

I don't know if bubble tea is ever kosher--maybe in Israel--but I'd also wonder about the bracha on that.

Comment: I've never had this drink before. Is it like orange juice with pulp?

Comment: @DoubleAA I would say it's closer to bubble tea in that you have to chew the pieces of pulp (which are actually gel, they say). You're missing out!

Comment: the question is good.  Is there people who eat Aloe Vera in other circumstances?

Comment: @kouty Very good followup question and I'm not sure. I think the answer is "yes," although I don't know if it's only weird people.

Comment: For other readers - I gather the motive behind @kouty's question is based on a general rule that if it is uncommon for people in an area to eat a raw fruit or vegetable, then the bracha on it is *shehakol*. E.g., in the U.S., if you eat raw chili peppers, the bracha would be *shehakol*. In India, where eating raw chilis is quite common, from what I understand, you might be saying *ha'etz*.

Comment: It's popular more among the hispanic crowd, but yes, people DO consume aloe vera...

Comment: Does it matter that they probably don't consume it in the form it is in in the drink? (I'd assume it does...)

Comment: One easy way to largely narrow down the possibility, SAH. Buy a bottle and see if the "pulp" pieces look anything like the plant itself. (if you're not sure, you can find strips of fresh aloe plant in numerous NYC area produce market, esp. in Hispanic areas. Buy one and open it up to extract the sap so you get an idea.) If it doesn't (which I suspect that it doesn't), then it's most likely *shehakol*.

Comment: @DanF Good idea! I'll try to remember to buy some aloe when I next see it. As for the drink, it's sitting in my fridge until I can figure out the bracha...