What is the proper beracha on boba
According to Halacha, what is the proper beracha when drinking boba with boba balls? Is it shehakol or something else?

Dupe? - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/what-is-the-correct-bracha-for-those-israeli-aloe-drinks

From what I can see on https://www.brachos.org/, there is no mention of boba or tapioca. There is however mention of tea, which is shehakol. In terms of things similar to boba tea, I was able to find berachos on acai bowls, milkshakes/ice cream, different types of milk, sherbet, soda, sorbet, and whipped cream all under the shekakol section of the website. You should ask your LOR in case there is anything else added that was not mentioned, like some berries/veggies like strawberries/bananas/spinach(Borei Pri Hoadama), fruits like mango or blueberries(Borei Pri Ha/Etz), or grape products(Borei Pri Hagafen).
