Does boba from a non-Jewish store need a Hechsher
According to Halacha, does boba bought from a non-Jewish store need a Hechsher? Or no, is it kosher unless shown otherwise?

Sounds waaaaay too complicated to say "easy without a hechsher."

https://thebetterboba.com/is-boba-kosher/#:~:text=Typically%20made%20from%20tea%20leaves,flavorings%20that%20need%20kosher%20certification.

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/141724/759

The CRC Kashrus Organization tweeted in 2018 that Plain Tapioca Pearls Do Not Need A Hechsher, however this should likely be verified to determine if this is still their opinion. Even if it is their opinion still, it DOES NOT necessarily mean that purchasing a tea from a non-jewish store will be allowed. You may need to verify in the store that the Boba they use is unflavored by asking to see the packaging, and also ensure that the rest of the drink they prepare is up to proper kosher standards regarding flavorings, etc.
